# why am I getting Null Pointer Exception while trying to check if the username is already present in the database?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, swagger

This code is to check if the user is already registered to the application or not ,and I am getting null pointer exception while checking if the similar username exists in the database

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
@PostMapping("/register")
public String registeruser(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestBody UserDetails requestData) {
String userName = requestData.getUsername();
        System.out.println("checking user");
        System.out.println(userName);
        System.out.println(uDao.existsById(userName));// I AM GETTING ERROR HERE
if ((uDao.existsById(userName))) {
            throw new UserAlreadyExistException("You have already registered. please log in");
        }
String userRole = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute("role");
if (!userRole.equalsIgnoreCase("productmaster") || !userRole.equalsIgnoreCase("admin")||!userRole.equalsIgnoreCase("Retailer")) {
throw new InvalidUserRoleException("you are not authorized to add the products");
}
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
boolean newuser = true;
UserDetails user = new UserDetails(requestData.getUsername(), requestData.getPassword()),requestData.getUserRole());
if (newuser = uservice.add(user)) {
return "User successfully added";
}
return "User is not added";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either the `uDao` or `userName` is `null`. The parameter of `existsById` must not be null. Check out the documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#existsById(ID)).

Comment: as you can see, I printed out the username to see if its null but no its printing the username how do I check if existbyid is null ?

Comment: then the dao object "uDao" shoud be null